# Are Antiderivatives Infinite?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a college Calculus student seeing antiderivatives for the first time. I was reasoning through one of the proofs when I realized that you can take an infinite number of antiderivatives? Is this accurate? You can't take an infitite number of derivatives, because at some point you'll be left with a constant which goes to zero. But, antiderivatives seem to be endless? So, integrals are infinite?

Comment: Consider a function like $e^x$...you can take infinitely many derivatives of that.  It's only polynomials that eventually go to $0$ this way.

Comment: The are some functions you cannot differentiate infinitely often but the reason is not that they become zero (which doesn't need to happen, check lulu's comment). Also note that the function $f(x) = 0$ can be differentiated infinitely often. It's just not very interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question, but you are a little confused.

You can't always keep differentiating, but not for the reason you suggest. There is no problem differentiating $x^2$ infinitely often. It's true that you get the $0$ function pretty soon, but that function is differentiable - it happens to be its own derivative.

However, you can differentiate the function $x|x|$ just once. Its derivative has a corner at the origin so is not differentiable.

You can always keep antidifferentiating - but you may not be able to do that with a nice formula. When you study the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus you will find out that you can always find areas (and hence antiderivatives) the hard way, with a limit of sums of rectangles, even if you can't guess a formula.